# Java - Can't read in special characters from a text file

Tags: java, file, input, special-characters, character

I am writing a program which searches for words in a text file (say B) in another dictionary text file (say A) to compare efficiencies of different sorting algorithms.

Anyway, my problem is when one of these source text files has a special character such as "µ." First of all, to save a text file with such a character in windows, notepad says I have to change the encoding from  ANSI to something else like UTF-8.

My program crashes when it encounters a line with a special character. Specifically at the point when this word is compared to a word in the other dictionary text file using the compareTo method. It crashes with a NullPointerException.

I have printed out the special character to see that "µ" is represented as "Âµ" and strange characters are always present on the first line ("ï»¿").

I am using a Scanner for file input:

```
inputStream = new Scanner (new FileInputStream(args[0]));
```

I have tried a FileReader as well

In general, how would I read special characters, or words containing special characters? And would these characters be compatiable with the built in compareTo method or would I have to find another way to order them?

Comment: I think you are showing too few code. (arg[0] looks like a parameter to a 'publich static void main(String[] args)' to me. Are you calling your program with a parameter?)

Answer (score 4):

There is no ANSI encoding, there is only ASCII. Use Notepad++ to create correct UTF-8 encoded files. Open the file in Java with a [reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) which takes in an encoding.

Comment: This program is to be tested "using any input" according to the markets. I have no control over how they save the text file. I am just concerned about what will happen if they do decide to put a special character in the input text file. But in general, how do I read special characters

Comment: You can't if you don't know the encoding. All you can do is use ICU4J to guess the encoding. Anything else **will** fail.

Comment: You were right about Notepad++. I created the textfile using Notepad++ and the program no longer crashes. However, now these characters are being displayed as "?". I am using jGrasp if its of any use

Comment: What does jGrasp do with that file? If it has to read it and you cannot provide an encoding, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]), "UTF-8");
```

or

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(args[0]), "UTF-8"));
```

**InputStreams** are for binary byte data, **Readers** are on characters with their encoding.

It seems there is a "BOM" character in front of the text, a zero width space, which serves to mark the text as UTF-8. This could have been deleted, but then Windows does not recognize UTF-8. In the scanner you might wish to skip it.

Comment: I tried creating the Scanner as you said, however, I still got the same error as before

Comment: It is a common misconcept to add a BOM to UTF-8 encoded files. The BOM is here [discouraged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) becaue UTF-8 is byte-order agnostic. Java won't add a BOM by default.

Comment: I tried the BufferedReader as well, and still got the same error on the line    dictionary[position].compareTo(searchTerm) < 0  where searchTerm is the string with the special character. This program works for non-special character input

Comment: Can you read the file with Notepad? If Notepad shows them correctly and Notepad says the file is in UTF-8 then the error is to be found elsewhere. More likely it is not UTF-8 but Cp1252 / ... or messed up code. You can use the freeware JEdit to reload a file in several encodings.

Comment: It turns out that Notepad was the culprit. If I create the same text file using Notepad++,  my program doesn't crash. However, it still displays the special characters as ?. For example, β, is displayed as ? in the output

Comment: Then the output encoding must be set too, possibly with Unicode font. Look at `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` whereto to encode.